# DirectX 11: Почему происходит ошибка, когда я пытаюсь использовать текстуру, написанную вручную?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, direct3d

Моя программа представляла собой текстурированный «куб». Текстура эта бралась из файла формата PNG, используя метод `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile`. Всё отлично работало, пока я не попробовал вручную «написать» простую 2x2 текстуру и использовать её.

```
void InitTextures()
{
    //D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(dev, L"texture.png", NULL, NULL, &pTexture, NULL);

    ID3D11Texture2D* theTexture;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&texDesc, sizeof(texDesc));
    texDesc.Width = 2;
    texDesc.Height = 2;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    texDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    int texData[4][4] = {
        { 0, 255, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 255, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 255, 0 },
        { 0, 255, 0, 0 },
    };
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA theData;
    theData.pSysMem = &texData;
    theData.SysMemPitch = sizeof(int) * 4;
    theData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    dev->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, &theData, &theTexture);
    dev->CreateShaderResourceView(theTexture, NULL, &pTexture);

    // ...
}
```

Показываться стало лишь цвет фона (куб исчез). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

**ИЗМЕНЕНО** Я установил texDesc.Format на DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, а также изменил тип массива с int на uint8_t и получил это. Куб отображается, но не так, как я ожидал: с четырьмя цветными пикселями со всех сторон.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `::std::uint8_t texData[16]` формат же `R8G8B8A8` 8 - количество бит на канал

Comment: @user7860670 исправил на DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT, но всё равно не работает.

Comment: Используйте `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` Я не думаю, что беззнаковые форматы где-то поддерживаются

Comment: Куб стал отображаться, но не верно.

Comment: После изменения типа массива надо еще и SysMemPitch поменять

Comment: Кубик снова исчез :)

Comment: А что вы изменили? SysMemPitch  кстати изначально тоже неправильный был. А отладочный слой включен? Неужели он ни на что не ругается, если отрисовка пропадает?

Comment: По документации вроде говорится что-то про размер строки в байтах sizeof(uint8_t) * 4. А что за отладочный слой?

Comment: Это все из-за копипасты в говнокоде... размер пикселя -  `sizeof(uint8_t) * 4` а, размер строки - размер пикселя умноеженный на ширину

Comment: Отладочный слой включается когда устройство создается с флагом DEBUG

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142660/discussion-between-arkady-and-user7860670).